# Background Worker cancel async not working

Tags: .net, vb.net, backgroundworker

### Program Logic

I'm running a background worker for reading and writing files. For checking if cancel button is clicked, I've created a method called "check_bgWorkerCancelled()" and this is supposed to handle all the events if cacellation is pending.

### Problem

When I click the cancel button, the worker keeps running. When I click back the start button, the old process keeps running.

### Code: For checking cancellation

```
' Method: To check is cancellation is pending
    Private Sub check_bgWorkerCancelled()
        ' check if cancellation is pending
        If bgWorker_Scanner.CancellationPending = True Then
            ' background worker cancel asynchronous operating
            If bgWorker_Scanner.IsBusy Then
                Try 'try to
                    ' cancel the threads
                    bgWorker_Scanner.CancelAsync()
                    ' dispose the background worker
                    bgWorker_Scanner.Dispose()
                Catch ex As Exception 'if exception
                    ' invoke error
                    utils.invoke_msg(3, "Worker Error", ex.Message.ToString)
                    Me.Close() 'close form
                End Try
            End If
            isScanning = False 'set scanning to false
            Try
                ' invoke to bypass illegal cross threading UI update
                BeginInvoke(CType(Sub()
                                      progressBar1.Value = 0
                                      txtStatus.Text = "Cancelled"
                                      txtCalmDown.Text = ""
                                      btnToggleScan.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "/res/malware_scanner/rocket.png")
                                  End Sub, MethodInvoker))
            Catch ex As Exception : End Try
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub
```

### Tried Solutions

I've tried the following solutions, but none worked:

**Tried to check for cancellation inside DoWork event**

```
Private Sub bgWorker_Scanner_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgWorker_Scanner.DoWork
    If bgWorker_Scanner.CancellationPending = True Then
        e.CancelAsync()
        bgWorker_Scanner.dispose()
    End If
End Sub
```

**Tried to check for cancellation and collect garbage**

```
Private Sub bgWorker_Scanner_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgWorker_Scanner.DoWork
    If bgWorker_Scanner.CancellationPending = True Then
        e.CancelAsync()
        bgWorker_Scanner.dispose()
        GC.Collect()
    End If
End Sub
```

**Tried to do the above inside Try-Catch statements**

```
Private Sub bgWorker_Scanner_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgWorker_Scanner.DoWork
    If bgWorker_Scanner.CancellationPending = True Then
        If bgWorker_Scanner.IsBusy Then
            Try
                e.CancelAsync()
                bgWorker_Scanner.dispose()
                GC.Collect()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: Debug Image]

Is there any way to end the background worker without having to close the form completely? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If `bgWorker_Scanner.CancellationPending Then 'Do something  e.Cancel = True End If`. Call `[BackGroundWorker].CancelAsync()` from the *outside*.

Comment: @Jimi I called the `CancelAsync()` from a button. Now there seems to be a different problem for some reason.. There is the waiting cursor icon and the button is disabled by default. I didn't set this, but I guess Windows is doing it automatically.. I can't access the button unless the whole operation is finished :'(

Comment: You clearly do not know how to use a `BackgroundWorker` properly. Go [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?471889) to learn. Post #19 contains an example of cancellation.

Comment: I hope you're not still trying to dispose of the BackGroundWorker inside `DoWork`  or calling `GC.Collect()`. If you're in a loop when `CancelAsync` is called, exit the loop (after `e.Cancel = True`).